# iPhone UITextField: how to insert new line by the return key?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uitextfield

I want to get a carriage return/new line by hitting the return key
on an UITextField's keyboard.
I've found out, that textFieldShouldReturn gets called.

But how do I insert a carriage return in the text field?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using a UITextField instead of a UITextView? The UITextView was created specifically for allowing multiple lines of editable text.

Comment: Bummer... Thanks, that solved my problem! I haven't thought about that. Have a nice day! :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use a UITextView instead. UITextFields are meant for single line input whereas UITextViews support multi-line input.